# How could I enable vim clipboard without sudo and x11 installed?

Tags: vimrc, os-clipboard

I am given an account on a new server these days. The new server does not have x11 install, neither do I have sudo. So I cannot install system packages, and I cannot compile with the option `-with-x`.

But I still want to use vim when I am working on my server, and I need to use the clipboard feature to allow me to copy the contents from and to the vim and other places. How could I do this pleaes?

=====
Edit: 
I got to find that the clipboard provided by the terminal can help. I could paste contents to vim with `ctrl`+`shift`+`v`. But the hot key of `ctrl`+`shift`+'c' does not work in the vim. how could I copy from vim like I copy from terminal?

Comment: Can't you compile Vim and install it to a directory owned by your user that you'll add to your `$PATH`? This way you shouldn't need `sudo`.

Comment: @statox Hi, I can compile my own vim, but I cannot use `-with-x` option anyway. Can I copy to system board without `-with-x` compiled?

Comment: I would say that you don't need `-X11`, `+clipboard` should be enough but maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 3):

#### Checking for X11-clipboard support in terminal

From the console, type:

```
vim --version | grep clipboard
```

If you see `+clipboard` or `+xterm_clipboard`, you are good to go. If it's `-clipboard` and `-xterm_clipboard`, you will need to look for a version of Vim that was compiled with clipboard support.

#### Installing clipboard support

On Debian and Ubuntu, to obtain clipboard support install the package `vim-gtk` or `vim-gnome` (**not** `vim-tiny`).

```
sudo apt install vim-gtk3 # go for vim-gtk if vim-gtk3 is not available
```

Reopen Vim and it should work.

For other operating systems and a reference, check [this](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Accessing_the_system_clipboard).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the clipboard directly from Vim, you'll need a version compiled with either the `+clipboard` or `+xterm_clipboard` features. On non-macOS Unix systems, those generally require at least X11 libraries. Without those features, Vim itself has no way of talking to the clipboard. You'll also need X forwarding enabled on your SSH connection (`ssh -X`).

Without those features, you can copy and paste from your terminal, but the copy will be only from the data you highlight with your mouse (then copy with Ctrl-Shift-C), just like at the shell. You can also use a terminal multiplexor like screen or tmux (running your remote Vim inside them) and configure it to copy and paste regions from the screen.

Answer (score 0):

First, install `xclip` (e.g., `yay -S xclip`).

Next, open your vim config file (e.g., `~/.config/nvim/init.vim`).

Finally, add shortcuts:

```
set clipboard=unnamed,unnamedplus
nnoremap yy Vdugv<esc>
vnoremap y dugv<esc>
vnoremap p P        "<-- This is optional shortcut.
```

Comment: Mappings aren’t necessary but could use explanation. In particular the nnoremap on yy seems superfluous (and would be more simply `yyV` if the line selection was important to you). Similarly `ygv` should work in first xnoremap. Second is basically `P` in recent Vims.